# How to add default value if given property does not exist in lodash template

Tags: javascript, lodash

Is it possible to add default value, if particular property does not exist in the given object in lodash template?

```
_.templateSettings.interpolate = /{{([\s\S]+?)}}/g;

var template=_.template("Hi {{name}}, Your age is {{age}}");

var user={'name':'Madura','email':'madura@s.com'};

var res=template(user);
```

When run above code, I get following error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: age is not defined

What I expect is "Hi Madura, Your age is"

Comment: Use `Object.assign()` or `_.assign()` to copy the default values if not passed.

Comment: No. I don't want to change my object. I want to change template setting or behavior to do it by itself. Because my template string is dynamic. So I don't know the properties in advance. Therefore, I can't assign property to user object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No, it is not possible**

Lodash is a simple templating engine to solve the general use cases. If you need more powerful templating engine, try [mustache](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/)